# ERROR: Packet for query is too large (1273178 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, netbeans-8.2

quiero subir un archivo PDF a mi base de datos, en el cuál el campo esta configurado como   mediumblob. El Programa en java me funciona cuando guardo PDFs pequeños, sin embargo cuando quiero subir un archivo que pesa 1 mega, me sale el mensaje de:

> Packet for query is too large (1273178 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.

No se donde modificar eso que me esta pidiendo, intente cambiar a longblob pero sigue igual. Uso XAMPP como servidor y PhPMyAdmin como SGBD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto debes cambiarlo en la configuración del gestor de BD, entiendo que estás usando MySQL por usar XAMPP.

Tienes que ir al fichero de configuración my.ini y hacer el cambio, normalmente tiene una ruta parecida a esta:

```
rutaXampp/mysql/bin/my.ini
```

Añades lo siguiente:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```

Donde 16 son los MB que necesites.

Luego reinicias MySQL a través del acceso directo de XAMPP.

Comment: Gracias! Seguía perdido sobre donde modificar pero por suerte lo alcance a ver [mysqld], más abajo estaban otros parámetros y en medio de todos ellos estaba max_allowed_packet = 1M, lo modifiqué a 20 MB y se solucionó.

Comment: Me alegro que hayas solucionado. Para eso estamos, para ayudar. Saludos.